# Struts2 ResultPath per package or something similar

Tags: struts2, struts

Currently, we can define a global path that'll be used for all results, under all packages.

I have different paths for different results and hence, is it possible to have the resultPath package wise ?

Or is there something that can help me achieve this ?

Obviously, I don't want to write the complete result-location in every-result, neither I want to change at every place if the location changes.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to [use `@ResultPath` on a Class by Class basis](https://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts2-plugins/struts2-convention-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/convention/annotation/ResultPath.html);

apply it to some `abstract baseAction`s, one per package.

All other actions will extend the one of their `<package>`, inheriting the ResultPath setting.

Comment: I'm not using convention actually, I prefer the XML way. Is there any solution for this style ?